# How do I integrate ServiceStack and DotNetNuke to provide REST services within a DNN authenticated context?

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-2, dotnetnuke, servicestack

DotNetNuke 6.2 has a Services Framework that does something similar
http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/DotNetNuke-6-2-Developer-Quick-Start.aspx#Services_Framework_18

> > The single biggest convenience of Services Framework is that authentication, authorization and establishing a DotNetNuke context are all built in.

How do I integrate ServiceStack (http://servicestack.net) with DotNetNuke to provide authentication, authorization and establish a DotNetNuke context? Any pointers?

Comment: if you are willing to release your ServiceStack implementation under a DNN compatible license (e.g. MIT or similar, not GPL), I would be very interested in helping out.

Comment: Will try to integrate SS and DNN. If it works out, I will release under an MIT license.

Comment: Did you ever get servicestack working with DotNetNuke?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the DNN implementation, so I can tell you about how it works.  I don't know the details of ServiceStack so I can't tell you how to apply it there.  When I first set out to build this, I expected it to be much more complicated than it actually is.  You really only need a handful of calls into the core.

Establishing context and authentication occurs during initialization of the DnnController.  One of the great things about DNN being all open source is that all these sort of details are public.  Here is a link to the [DnnController.cs](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/67071#1116564)

And here are the most interesting bits:

```
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        LoadDnnContext(requestContext.HttpContext);
        AuthenticateRequest(requestContext.HttpContext, PortalSettings.PortalId);
    }

    protected virtual void AuthenticateRequest(HttpContextBase context, int portalId)
    {
        if (!context.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            BasicAuthenticator.Instance.TryToAuthenticate(context, portalId);
        }

        if (!context.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            DigestAuthenticator.Instance.TryToAuthenticate(context, portalId);
        }

        MembershipModule.AuthenticateRequest(context, true /*allowUnknownExtension*/);
    }

    protected virtual void LoadDnnContext(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        var domainName = TestableGlobals.Instance.GetDomainName(context.Request);
        var alias = TestablePortalAliasController.Instance.GetPortalAliasInfo(domainName);

        int tabId;
        ValidateTabAndModuleContext(context, alias.PortalID, out tabId);

        var portalSettings = new PortalSettings(tabId, alias);

        context.Items["PortalSettings"] = portalSettings;
    }
```

The Service Framework forces all routes into the form {unique portal path}/DesktopModules/{ModuleName}/API/{url} .  The unique portal path is important to easily identifying the portal to which the request was sent.  In most cases DNN will allow a URL of the form /Default.aspx?portalid=n, but Service Framework won't accept that, it requires that the request path match the portal alias e.g. mysite.com/childportal/...  This requirement ensures that GetDomainName() will work.

I should mention that the TestableXXX classes are in the Internal namespace and therefore are not part of the official public API, and are subject to breaking changes between releases.  Most of the methods on the classes have a public analog which is harder to mock but otherwise equivalent.  If it is reasonable for you to make small code fixes before upgrading your servers, feel free to use the Testables.  If you don't have complete control over the upgrades of your servers you should avoid the .Internal namespaces.

Service Framework supports authentication against the permission of a specific module instance.  Services tied to a module must provider tab and module ids.  If your services are not module specific you may omit this, and use a tabid of -1 in the PortalSettings.

ServiceFramework has it's own implementations of basic and digest auth since MVC does not provide them.  I beleive that ServiceStack does provide Basic and Digest, so you probably only need to make the call to MembershipModule.AuthenticateRequest().

Comment: Thanks Scott. I will try integrate the two based on the information you provided. Will let you know how this goes.

Comment: Hi Scott - Can you DM me on twitter @SoftwareWeaver. I have some questions on Routing